# VBA returns [object] when using Doc.getElementsByTagName. Can't locate correct TagName from browser

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble locating the correct tag name from Chrome. When I run the following code all that is returned is "[object]". Does anyone have any suggestions to pull in the correct field?

Here's [the website](http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/address?street=1308+Lapwing+Rd&city=Edmond&state=OK&zip=73003&benchmark=4&vintage=4) I'm attempting to pull information. Specifically Census Tract but at this point if someone could show me how to return any information I will mine the correct one.

Here's my code, currently running the output to a MsgBox just to find the right field. From there I will reenable to `for` statement and make the URL in the VBA dynamic. Also note that I've attempted to use `getElementsByName` but no progress there either:

```
Sub censusTract()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'For i = 2 To lastRow
 Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
 'IE.Visible = True
 IE.navigate "http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/address?street=1308+Lapwing+Rd&city=Edmond&state=OK&zip=73003&benchmark=4&vintage=4"
 Do
 DoEvents
 Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
 Set Doc = IE.document
 Dim sDD As String
 'sDD = Doc.getElementsByTagName("br")(0)
 sDD = Doc.getElementsByName("pl_gov_census_geo_geocoder_domain_AddressResult")(0)
 MsgBox sDD
 'IE.Quit
 'sht.Cells(i, 41).Value = sDD
'Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you expecting instead of `[object]`?

Comment: I'm hoping to see the result of the `<br>` element that shows "TRACT: ...".

When I inspect element on the webpage I can see the field I want I'm just not sure how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.  All you need to do is pull the correct data from the object.  You can use one of the following

```
sDD = Doc.getElementsByName("pl_gov_census_geo_geocoder_domain_AddressResult").item(0).innerText
sDD = Doc.getElementsByName("pl_gov_census_geo_geocoder_domain_AddressResult").item(0).innerHTML
sDD = Doc.getElementsByName("pl_gov_census_geo_geocoder_domain_AddressResult").item(0).outerHTML
```

Right now its just pulling the object, adding innerText, innerHTML or outerHTML should pull your result.

Once you have that pulled you may want to split the results into an array so you can do what you need with each of the elements.  the code below should get you started.

```
Sub censusTract()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, v As Variant, block As Variant, x As Integer


Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'For i = 2 To lastRow
 Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
 'IE.Visible = True
 IE.navigate "http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/address?street=1308+Lapwing+Rd&city=Edmond&state=OK&zip=73003&benchmark=4&vintage=4"
 Do
 DoEvents
 Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
 Set Doc = IE.document
 Dim sDD As String
 'sDD = Doc.getElementsByTagName("br")(0)
 sDD = Doc.getElementsByName("pl_gov_census_geo_geocoder_domain_AddressResult").Item(0).innerText
 block = Split(sDD, vbLf)
 x = 2 'start column
 For Each v In block
  If v <> "" Then
    Cells(i, x).Value = v
    x = x + 1
  End If
Next v
 'IE.Quit
 'sht.Cells(i, 41).Value = sDD
'Next i
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Progress! Thank you. When I `MsgBox` the `innerHTML` one it returns a lot of information, in that output is the single field I need. How should I go about drilling even further to pull a single `<br>`?

Comment: I just posted a simple parsing technique that you can review.

Comment: You can also split the string like I did using the <br> as the delimiter.  You may want to try just using the innertext  like I posted.  Then you can check if its blank and then ignore it or whatever else you need to do with it.

Comment: The code you posted prints the information broken out perfectly. I've never used the `Debug.Print` feature before. What's the best method to take a single `v` from your `for` statement and direct it to a cell?

Comment: Sorry I'm still figuring out the commenting part on Stackoverflow.  Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Depending on what your workbook looks like you may want to actually print your result on a different worksheet.  I typically use a variable called `resultRow` then I will just increase that right after I print out a value.

Comment: I've done the same thing 5 times in this conversation alone. 

That worked great. I can polish it from here; thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome.  Feel free to mark the answer as the chosen one so this question can be "closed"  Thanks again.